# Parse querystrings of a request as JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, request

I'm going to receive requests with a JSON object passed as querystring which will no longer have a JSON structure, it will be something like this:

```
http:/mysite/api/doSomething?name=name&address=address...
```

I need to store it as a String following a JSON structure, the problem is that the original JSON object passed as querystring may have attributes that are collections and I can't figure out a way to parse it back correctly.

Is there a Java function or a library to achieve this easily?

Comment: I use jackson library for JSON in Java. Check this out: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Does this library have a a function to convert a string like this: name=name&address=address into JSON ? Considering it may be a more complex structure like with collections like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using spring mvc/jersey in controller. In that case you can do something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mysite/api/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(
@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
     JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()){
        js.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
   String jsonString = js.toString();
}
```

Basically get all the queryparam and construct JSONObjcet, JACKSON library will not be of much use here.

Comment: I couldn't check it before because I had no idea how to convert a complex  JSON to querystring, now that I was able to check it I can say it kinda works but for this example of JSON it does something like this "address[addressName]" = "myAddress", "address[addressCity]" = "myCity", which is not really the JSON format, I still need to find how to fix that.

Comment: The JSON example I was refering to is : {  "addresses" : { "addressName" : "myAddress", "city" : "myCity" }  }

Comment: @Ayane I could not understand what do you mean, are you saying it does not work?

Comment: When it's a simple JSON it works, but when you have nested objects, it does what I said in my first comment, which  I guess is tecnically correct but I need to parse it as JSON format.

Comment: In that Case you can do
`js.put(entry.getKey(), new JSONObject(entry.getValue()));`
but the catch here is you have to know it is a json object or string.
hence calls for some hardcoding